# contourplot labels?

Tags: maple

I need to label my contours generated by using the contourplot function. Is this feasible in Maple? I have tried the advisor6 database found here http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/advisor/advisor6/advisor6.html, but it doesn't seem to work as I'm using Maple 17! Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is feasible with the **textplot** command. [This post on MaplePrimes](http://www.mapleprimes.com/posts/200163-CoolProp-Thermophysical-Properties-For-Maple) has a very thorough example of doing this. This is the generated plot:[image: P-h-T Chart for R134a]

Comment: I did not see the detailed example that you refer to. Textplot is for manual labelling. I am looking for a mechanism for automatic labelling of contours.

Comment: The detailed example is in the zip file attached to the MaplePrimes post. There is no mechanism for automatic labelling of contours; textplot is as good as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is quite old, this solution might help others.

The [labelledcontourplot](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/advisor/advisor6/h27r1.htm) function from the [Maple Advisor Database](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/advisor/) might help you. A detailed description and examples can be found under the first link.

Quote from the developers web site:
'The Maple Advisor Database is a project of the Symbolic Computation Group of the University of British Columbia, under the direction of Robert Israel. [...] The Maple Advisor Database is protected by copyright, but is made freely available to the Maple community.'